# Give application instances their own IPs? Extremely lightweight containerization?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, lightweight, container

About two years ago I received a note with a method, but I was not able to find the note or the method right now.  Anyone know the easiest way to achieve this?

J.E.B.

Comment: Network namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, here is a simple script that creates a new network namespace, and starts an `xterm` in it, so all actions in there happens in that namespace. It also connects the namespace to the main namespace by a veth-pair.

Put all veth-endpoints in the main namespace in a bridge so multicasting is trivial (or add a multicast router, if you want), run your applications from the xterm (or modify the script), see if that already does what you want. You need to replace `your_userid` with the userid which should run the instances.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Setup network namespace with veth pair, start xterm in it

# nsterm ns0 veth0 10.0.0 yellow 24
#

if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
   exit 1
fi

NS=${1:-ns0}
DEV=${2:-veth0}
DEV_A=${DEV}a
DEV_B=${DEV}b
ADDR=${3-:10.0.0}
ADDR_A=${ADDR}.254
ADDR_B=${ADDR}.1
MASK=${5:-24}
COL=${4:-yellow}

# echo ns=$NS dev=$DEV col=$COL mask=$MASK

ip netns add $NS
ip link add $DEV_A type veth peer name $DEV_B netns $NS
ip addr add $ADDR_A/$MASK dev $DEV_A
ip link set ${DEV}a up
ip netns exec $NS ip addr add $ADDR_B/$MASK dev $DEV_B
ip netns exec $NS ip link set ${DEV}b up
ip netns exec $NS ip route add default via $ADDR_A dev $DEV_B
ip netns exec $NS su -c "xterm -bg $COL &" your_userid
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the answer was and is [Firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com/).  Much simpler to handle than network namespaces.